# ImportError: cannot import name 'Bitrix24' from 'bitrix24'

Tags: python-3.x, bitrix

I installed this module https://github.com/gebvlad/bitrix24-python-sdk using pip

```
python3.8 -m pip install -I bitrix24-python-sdk
```

When I try to import this module

```
from bitrix24 import Bitrix24
```

I am getting the next error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/vinni/Documents/GitHub/funnel.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bitrix24 import Bitrix24
ImportError: cannot import name 'Bitrix24' from 'bitrix24' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bitrix24/__init__.py)
```

OS - MacOS 10.15
Python - 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, I solved it by using

`from bitrix24.bitrix24 import Bitrix24`

To put it simply, I looked at the modules-directory of Python.

`from bitrix24` is navigating to the directory,
`.bitrix24` is referring to the bitrix24.py file inside this directory, and `import Bitrix24` calls the class inside this file.

Hope this also helps you find module errors in the future!